# Turning Type to something passable to T

Tags: c#, generics

I'm currently trying to make a simple Web API framework that is essentially "controller-less", but loads controllers, modals, and what nots from dlls.

On startup, the framework does the following

1. Go though the DLLs in the Plugin Folder -GOT THIS
2. Look for, and invoke the "CacheRegistration" and "ContextRegistration" methods (which adds the type the list accordingly) - GOT THIS

(After going through the DLLs)

3. Inject the model types into `OnModelCreating` (then create the database) - Check
4. Iterate though the list and call `Cacher.RegisterModel<T>()`; (Gets the data from server and loads them into memory)

My problem is how do I call `Cacher.RegisterModel<T>` just buy using a Type. Some articles are pointing me to `Activator.CreateInstance()` but I don't need an instance, I need something that i can pass into T.

The Cacher can be refractored if needed

EDIT
On a non dynamic system EF would just do all the work on #3. As for #4, I would create a CacheConfigurator class and dump everything there and call it from global.ascx

CacherConfigurator

```
public static void Initialize()
{
    Cacher<Customer>.SyncData();
    Cacher<Items>.SyncData();
    // Other models
}
```

Comment: Please include a code example of how you would do 3 and 4 if you did not have a dynamic plugin system and instead where just hardcoding in types.

Answer (score 3):

```
Cacher<Customer>.SyncData();
Cacher<Items>.SyncData();
```

If you’re looking to replace this in a dynamic fashion, then reflection is (still) the way to go:

```
// this comes from somewhere dynamic
Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(Customer), typeof(Items) };

foreach (Type t in types)
{
    var m = typeof(Cacher<>).MakeGenericType(t).GetMethod("SyncData", BindingFlags.Static);
    m.Invoke(null, null);
}
```

This will iterate through all the types, get the generic type `Cacher<T>` and call the static method `SyncData` on that type.